# PyQt5 "Прекращена работа программы Python" Почему такое происходит?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, исключения, обработка-ошибок

Доброго времени суток! Осваиваю PyQt5  и пытаюсь написать простенький словарь.
Программа запускается, но при ее закрытии появляется сообщение "Прекращена работа программы Python". 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код вот такой:

```
import datrie

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox

from ui_dict_form import UiDictForm


class DictWindow(QWidget, UiDictForm):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setup_ui(self)
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.dict = datrie.Trie.load('file_dict.dict')


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
                                     "Вы действительно хотите выйти?",
                                      QMessageBox.Yes | 
                                      QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.close()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DictWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

На данный момент я понял что такое сообщение появляется когда в коде присутствует такая строчка: `self.dict = datrie.Trie.load('file_dict.dict')`, если же ее убрать/закоментировать, то такое сообщение не появляется.
Использую ОС Windows 7 64bit, Python 3.5, PyQt5. Помогите разобраться/избавиться от этой проблемы.

Comment: запускайте скрипт так, чтобы видеть traceback. К примеру, из консоли с помощью python.exe

Comment: Я как раз так и делаю. Но в ничего не появляется

Comment: если datrie это Си расширение и на уровне Си ошибка, то попробуйте faulthandler модуль включить, чтобы trackback увидеть.

Answer (score 4):

Для отлова исключений, которые происходят в слотах Qt, добавьте функцию `log_uncaught_exceptions`.

Когда будет исключение, [вы увидите его и где оно произошло](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a4352244cab62335c2e3c1367e87720cdbea27c1/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/qt_log_uncaught_exceptions.py#L11), что поможет исправить ошибку.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit(1)


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

    app = QApplication([])

    button = QPushButton("DON'T PUSH ME!")
    button.resize(200, 200)
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: 1 / 0)
    button.show()

    app.exec()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: без `sys.excepthook` traceback бы в консоли был напечатан (автор вопроса утверждает, что в консоли ничего не видно). На уровне Си может падать приложение.

Comment: код в ответе без `sys.excepthook` не напечатает в консоли, сами попробуйте, у автора такая же проблема, только кода больше

Comment: Код (ожидаемо) печатает исключение в терминале на моей машине. Вы уверены, что pythonw для запуска не использовали?

Comment: Разобрался. Такая ошибка как у автора в вопросе возникала при запуске из PyCharm. Если запускать вне IDE, то при python.exe ошибка отображалась в консоли (если не перехватывалось excepthook), а в pythonw.exe консоль не появлялась, поэтому программа тихо падала

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь явно не в pyqt, проблема либо в модуле `datrie`, либо(что наиболее вероятно) в файле `file_dict.dict`. Возможно, его содержимое не соответствует нужному формату