# Передать значения из виджета в скрипт питон

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

написал модуль питон назвал `strorint`
как будет выглядеть код передачи введённых значений в окне в скрипт, и отображения в строке состояния нажатых `старт("чтот запущено")` и `стоп ("Остановлен")`, `r=время перезапуска`  и `n=ввести букву или цифру`?
книгу почитал и так понимаю в созданной форме (с расширением ру) надо будет прописывать каждую функцию?И как допустим будет написан код передачи `print("Строка или буква",n)` или `print("Цифра", n)` в виджет (потом на окне дорисую `lineEdit`) `LineEdit`?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time

r = 7
n = t
def strorint():
    if n == str:
        print("Строка или буква",n)
    else:
        n == int
        print("Цифра", n)

while True:
    print("Перезапуск")
    time.sleep(r)
    strorint()
```

создал окно в Qt5 Desiner и конвертнул в ру, назвал samplestrorint вот код

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(342, 263)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 111, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.doubleSpinBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.doubleSpinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 71, 31))
        self.doubleSpinBox.setObjectName("doubleSpinBox")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 141, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 80, 181, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 342, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Время перезапуска"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввести букву или цифру"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
```

[image: окно виджета]

Comment: А сам вопрос то какой? Вам нужно просто передавать данные из строки в консоль?

Comment: передать введённые значения в окне виджета в скрипт питон, при старте вывести в строку состояния "сатрт или стоп",и вывести  print в окно виджета! и ещё вопрос появился запускаю конвертированный файл ру и никакого окна не выводится надо дописать в конце окна виджета вроде этого: if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui_MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы запустить скрипт из конвертированного `Designer`(у меня это файл `token_ex.py`) используйте отдельный класс(виджет) и в него при помощи функции в конвертируемом файле `setup_UI` вы устанавливаете все виджеты в данный класс. После чего вы можете ссылаться на виджеты которые вы создали через `Designer`.

в данном случае при введении значения в `lineEdit` и нажатии на кнопку старт в консоль выведется ваша функция(немного переделанная потому что при вводе в `lineEdit` он всегда выводит строковое значение)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
import token_ex


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = token_ex.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Stop')
        self.ui.lineEdit.textEdited.connect(self.strorint)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage('Start'))
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage('Stop'))

    def strorint(self):
        try:
            n = int(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
            print("Цифра", n)
        except ValueError:
            r = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
            print("Строка или буква", r)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = ()
    n = ()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: я правильно понял?мне надо создать ещё один ру(вроде вашего примера) и уже с него он будет ссылаться на основную форму?и про отображении в строке состояния можно пример?ой и про привязку старт и стоп к запуску функции в strorint?старт то пишет запущен стоп то остановлен!простите уж ток изучаю и соответственно вопросов пока больше чем примеров.

Comment: @Олег на счёт ещё одного файла `.py` это зависит от вас но вообще чтобы не путаться желательно (лично для меня так) про привязку старта и стопа в примере есть привязка старта я думаю для стопа нет такой сильной необходимости просто пишете переменную к которой привязана кропкан и все, а строка состояния не совсем понятно что в ней должно быть. Для начало поставьте цель что вам нужно сделать и что не получается конкретно. Потому что вы сейчас задаёте вопросы а что для чего мне лично не совсем понятно. Додумывать ваш вопрос особо желания нету

Comment: нажал старт а в строке(Statusbar) состояния отобразится ну например программа запущена. И ещё про переменные в исполняемом файле питона переменные  "r"  и "n" сделать так r=() n =()? как будет выглядеть передача в исполняемый файл введеных значений из окна(виджета)?

Comment: @Олег обновил ответ

Comment: можно ещё такой вопрос а как отлавливаются ошибки в Qt5?приложени просто закрывается и всё, непонятно почему

Comment: @Олег [посмотрите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/802546/255866)